# Example/generator of direct upload a file to Amazon S3 (using POST)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, post, upload, generator

Is there a working example or a generator that will help me with creating a HTML form needed to upload a file directly to Amazon S3 servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple script that will generate a valid HTML: https://github.com/z-x/amazon-s3-direct-post-upload

You just need to edit first few lines in the PHP file and run the script.